# Rigorous mathematical definition of "much greater than" symbol

Tags: soft-question, definition

What does $f(x) \gg g(x)$ mean mathematically? How can we characterize "much greater than"?

Comment: I think this falls into the same category as "for *small* $x$," which is only clear (if I can use that word) from context.

Comment: Physicists tend to use it to mean "$g$ is so small it can be ignored", which often translates to taking a limit as $g\to0$. I don't think I've ever seen any of my pure math professors use it.

Comment: Engineers use it to get rid of things that would make the problem hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context and what kind of functions $f$ and $g$ are, etc.  One way is to say that $f(x) \gg g(x)$ if for any constant $c>0$ there exists some value $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) > c g(x)$ for all $x > x_0$.

Comment: You may use `\gg` (or `\ll`, if need be).

Answer (score 0):

I usually just think like this

$$f(x) + g(x) \sim f(x)$$

That is $g(x)$ can be neglected